Getting auth token from one server and setting it in outgoing request to another server not working on NGINX
I am trying to setup an Nginx configuration for an Nginx docker container, wherein I want to add an auth token to almost every request to remote server ( out of docker network ). The Auth token is generated and returned by making a call to another docker container. I tried to setup something as below and it makes a call to authServer, the token is generated and returned, but it fails with 400 error. I am testing this by making a curl/postman call.
load_module modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;

user  nginx;

events {
  worker_connections   1000;
}

http {

  upstream outgoingurl {   
    server outgoing.server.url.com;
  }

  upstream authServer {    
    server authtoken:8080;
  }

  upstream tokenServer {
   server localhost:8084; 
  }

  server {
      listen         8084;
      server_name    clm;
      proxy_ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certs/cert.pem;
      proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;

      location / {
        resolver 172.16.199.101; // Docker container for dns resolution 
        set $target http://authServer/;
        proxy_pass $target;     
      }
     
  }

  server {
      listen         8083;
      server_name    outgoing;

      location = /data/v1/products {
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        resolver 172.16.199.101; // Docker container for dns resolution
        auth_request /getAuthToken;
        set $target https://outgoingurl/;        
        proxy_pass $target;
      }

      location ~ /getAuthToken {
        resolver 172.16.199.101;
        set $outgoingTarget http://tokenServer/;
        proxy_pass $outgoingTarget;
        add_header X-Service-Token1 $upstream_http_accessToken;
        add_header X-Service-Token2 $upstream_http_accessToken;
      }     
  }
}

And the error I am getting is :
2024-10-04 07:52:37 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2024:11:52:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2953 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.42.0"
2024-10-04 07:53:02 192.168.65.1 - - [04/Oct/2024:11:53:02 +0000] "GET /data/v1/products HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.42.0"
2024-10-04 07:55:58 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2024:11:55:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2953 "-" "curl/8.6.0"
2024-10-04 07:56:58 2024/10/04 11:56:58 [error] 29#29: *14 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: <Client_IP>, server: outgoing, request: "GET /data/v1/products HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://<Upstream_IP>:80/", host: "localhost:8083"

curl/Postman Response:
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.27.2</center>
</body>
</html>

If I make a call to upstream url directly, without Nginx in between the call works fine and I get data back.
I was expecting that the authServer will return the token ( which it does currently ) and I will be able to set that in the header of outgoing request, but not sure what is going on. I am running all this on local docker.
